# Where are the cinnamon sound effect .ogg files located?

Tags: sound, cinnamon, effects

I just installed Cinnamon on Ubuntu.
The sound effects aren't working (e.g. 'swoosh' when changing to another workspace, and 'bing' when adjusting volume).

I went to the sound effects settings menu, and noticed that none of the effects were linked with any specific `.ogg` files. (Even if they are enabled.) Instead the audio file path for each points to my home directory.

[image]

I created a new user account, the sound effects for that account point to that home directory.

So, is there a way to reset all sound effects paths in cinnamon to their default path?

If not, what is the default path? (I can just manually set them again, if I know where to look.)

Edit: I initially said the sound effects were working after the clean install, but I think that's just my memory playing tricks on me (I did a few clean installs of different distros that day).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed Cinnamon via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

And certainly I found no sounds installed *by default* which is a bit annoying. However Ubuntu has several sound themes that can be installed:

```
andrew@athens:~$ apt-cache search sound | grep theme
sound-theme-freedesktop - freedesktop.org sound theme
ubuntu-sounds - Ubuntu's GNOME audio theme
kadu-themes - Additional icons and emoticons for Kadu
moblin-sound-theme - moblin sound theme
oxygen-sounds - Sounds for the Oxygen desktop theme
andrew@athens:~$
```

And I kitted my copy of Cinnamon out with the `oxygen-sounds` package:

```
sudo apt-get install oxygen-sounds
```

which leaves a nice sound theme that can be found in `/usr/share/sounds`.

Adding these sounds has to be done *manually* from within the 'Sound Effects menu of Cinnamon, sound by sound, but worked well enough. The available sounds:

```
andrew@athens:/usr/share/sounds$ ls  *.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Cant-Connect.ogg             Oxygen-Sys-App-Negative.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Connection-Lost.ogg          Oxygen-Sys-App-Positive.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Contact-In.ogg               Oxygen-Sys-Error-Printing.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Contact-Out.ogg              Oxygen-Sys-File-Open-Foes.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Error-On-Connection.ogg      Oxygen-Sys-List-End.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Highlight-Msg.ogg            Oxygen-Sys-List-Match-Multiple.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Internal-Error.ogg           Oxygen-Sys-List-Match-No.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Irc-Event.ogg                Oxygen-Sys-Log-In-Long.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Low-Priority-Message.ogg     Oxygen-Sys-Log-In.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Message-In.ogg               Oxygen-Sys-Log-In-Short.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Message-Out.ogg              Oxygen-Sys-Log-Out.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Network-Problems.ogg         Oxygen-Sys-Question.ogg
Oxygen-Im-New-Mail.ogg                 Oxygen-Sys-Special.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Nudge.ogg                    Oxygen-Sys-Trash-Emptied.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Phone-Ring.ogg               Oxygen-Sys-Warning.ogg
Oxygen-Im-Sms.ogg                      Oxygen-Window-All-Desktops-Not.ogg
Oxygen-Im-User-Auth.ogg                Oxygen-Window-All-Desktops.ogg
Oxygen-K3B-Finish-Error.ogg            Oxygen-Window-Close.ogg
Oxygen-K3B-Finish-Success.ogg          Oxygen-Window-Maximize.ogg
Oxygen-K3B-Insert-Medium.ogg           Oxygen-Window-Minimize.ogg
Oxygen-Sys-App-Error-Critical.ogg      Oxygen-Window-Move.ogg
Oxygen-Sys-App-Error.ogg               Oxygen-Window-Move-Stop.ogg
Oxygen-Sys-App-Error-Serious.ogg       Oxygen-Window-Shade-Down.ogg
Oxygen-Sys-App-Error-Serious-Very.ogg  Oxygen-Window-Shade-Up.ogg
Oxygen-Sys-App-Message.ogg
andrew@athens:/usr/share/sounds$
```

My advice is to experiment with this sound theme and perhaps some of the others and make up your own cocktail of sound...